# Delete lines of a stream without reading it into a string

Tags: c#, html, file-upload

Im recieving a stream with some data (in this case, an image I upladed on a html site which should then be saved in a folder).

The html upload puts the data into a "------WebKitFormBoundary" so I can't properly display the original file anymore.

I wanted to delete those lines from that stream (named "content"). But reading the file and saving it in a string corrupts my data, so I can't display it again as an image.

I tried reading certain bytes from the original stream, but the "------WebKitFormBoundary" part doesn't always have the same amount of bytes for every file.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

My code so far:

```
        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),"Folder", name, "doc1");
        var path2 = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Folder", name);
        CreateDirectory(path);

        using (var file = File.Create(path))
        {
            content.CopyTo(file);
        }

        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(path2, "doc1");
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(dirs[0]);
        File.WriteAllLines(dirs[0], lines.Skip(4).Take(lines.Count() - 2));
```

Thanks for everyone in advance!

EDIT: SOLVED! For everyone who might come here some day and have the same problem - I used this guide from 2009 and it actually worked: http://antscode.blogspot.de/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html

Hadn't had time to check how this magician actually did it, but implemented it, and voila, the files get uploaded without any problems.

Comment: why don't you  just use `bytes[]` instead of `string[]`?

Comment: That wouldn't change anything would it? The string[ ] is just storing the name of the file I'm trying to edit. The point that corrupts my file is when I use File.ReadAllLines, because that way I'm turning my bytes into a text file. But I have to do that so I can actually work with lines instead of bytes.

Comment: Ya, I meant instead of `ReadAllLines`, can you use `ReadAllBytes`?

Comment: Well, I have the same problem then as I had before. I can only tell him to skip some bytes, but the WebKitFormBoundary doesn't always have the same amount of bytes (e.g. when the file name is longer).